# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los botones "Iniciar subida" y "cancelar subida" del UC FileUpload en Genexus

Tags: genexus, fileupload, upload, usercontrol

Hola actualmente la funcionalidad de esos dos botones:
1: la funcionalidad del botón Iniciar subida, la tengo con la propiedad Auto Upload:True
por lo tanto el botón queda bloqueado. Y no es necesario que lo siga mostrando.
2: El botón "Cancelar subida", tampoco lo necesito. Por lo que necesito por lo menos ocultarlos.
¡Gracias!
[image: Quitar u ocultar botones]
Una vez modificada la propiedad, me deja de mostrar los dos botones de cancelar. Y quiero conservar el que aparece junto al archivo. En color rosa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas Omar?

Lo que tenes que hacer para lograr ese comportamiento es poner la propiedad:

"Hide Additional Buttons = false".

Con esa propiedad en false, se esconden los 2 botones que no precisas.

En el caso de que estes trabajando con una version anterior a GeneXus v17 u1, lo que podrias hacer es ocultar esos botones desde la clase "FileUpload" del Theme.

Se le asigna una clase de tipo "Button" a la propiedad "StartButtonClass" y a la propiedad "CancelButtonClass", que tenga "Display = None".

Saludos

Comment: Muy bien gracias Chona :D <br> Estoy usando Genexus16u9 y no me aparece la opción que me comentas. Lo intente plasmar desde la pestaña events, pero sin resultados. Tendrás alguna idea o alguna otra manera. De antemano gracias @Chona

Comment: Omar, edité mi respuesta para que contemple el caso en el que estes trabajando con versiones anteriores a v17 u1. Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Excelente la actualización, me ha quitado los dos botones. Pero veo que el cuarto botón de cancelar archivo (una vez cargado el archivo), también deja de mostrarse y ese si me gustaría mostrarlo. Busque alguna otra propiedad, me parece que están ligados ambos botones. Actualizo la imagen en la pregunta inicial. De todos modos, ya me ayudaste enormemente. Ten un excelente día.